# LTspice - Staircase saturation transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, electromagnetism, saturation

I am trying to simulate on a full bridge converter a staircase saturation transformer. I was thinking by adding a very little resistor on one leg of the full brigdge converter, it will in any case saturate the transformer. It would have shown that what ever the magneic material you take, due to the disparity of the components and PCB traces, it would saturate your transformer if there is no current control mode to regulate the flux density balance of the transformer

My simulation would integrate a non linear inductance for showing the effect of saturation. But I have some troubles to just make the staircase of linear inductor. Here is the simulation:

[image: ![enter image description here]!]

The "R_disparity" resistor represents the disparity between the two legs. Normally as I do not apply the same voltage at each time on the inductance it would make the inductance current diverge, but it does not work.

It does not diverge... Does anyone have an idea of what is happenning?

[image]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2016 1476
WIRE -1536 -528 -1536 -560
WIRE -1536 -416 -1536 -448
WIRE -976 -384 -1248 -384
WIRE -688 -384 -976 -384
WIRE -432 -384 -688 -384
WIRE -240 -384 -432 -384
WIRE 176 -368 160 -368
WIRE 320 -368 256 -368
WIRE 448 -368 384 -368
WIRE 544 -368 448 -368
WIRE 720 -368 624 -368
WIRE 720 -304 720 -368
WIRE -976 -288 -976 -384
WIRE -432 -288 -432 -384
WIRE -1248 -272 -1248 -384
WIRE -1024 -272 -1056 -272
WIRE -480 -272 -512 -272
WIRE -240 -272 -240 -384
WIRE 160 -272 160 -368
WIRE -1024 -224 -1056 -224
WIRE -480 -224 -512 -224
WIRE -1536 -208 -1536 -240
WIRE -1056 -192 -1056 -224
WIRE -512 -192 -512 -224
WIRE 720 -176 720 -224
WIRE 160 -128 160 -192
WIRE 272 -128 160 -128
WIRE -1536 -96 -1536 -128
WIRE -1248 -96 -1248 -208
WIRE -976 -96 -976 -208
WIRE -976 -96 -1248 -96
WIRE -816 -96 -976 -96
WIRE -432 -96 -432 -208
WIRE -432 -96 -736 -96
WIRE -240 -96 -240 -208
WIRE -240 -96 -432 -96
WIRE 272 -96 272 -128
WIRE 160 -48 160 -128
WIRE -976 -16 -976 -96
WIRE -1248 0 -1248 -96
WIRE -1024 0 -1056 0
WIRE -432 0 -432 -96
WIRE -240 0 -240 -96
WIRE -480 16 -512 16
WIRE -1024 48 -1056 48
WIRE -480 64 -512 64
WIRE -1536 96 -1536 64
WIRE 160 112 160 32
WIRE 176 112 160 112
WIRE 320 112 256 112
WIRE 448 112 448 -368
WIRE 448 112 384 112
WIRE -1536 208 -1536 176
WIRE -432 208 -432 80
WIRE 224 304 -112 304
WIRE 464 304 224 304
WIRE 464 336 464 304
WIRE 224 352 224 304
WIRE -432 368 -432 288
WIRE -112 384 -112 304
WIRE -112 384 -384 384
WIRE -352 432 -384 432
WIRE 224 464 224 432
WIRE 464 464 464 416
WIRE -1248 480 -1248 64
WIRE -1056 480 -1056 48
WIRE -1056 480 -1248 480
WIRE -976 480 -976 64
WIRE -976 480 -1056 480
WIRE -688 480 -976 480
WIRE -512 480 -512 64
WIRE -512 480 -688 480
WIRE -432 480 -432 448
WIRE -432 480 -512 480
WIRE -352 480 -352 432
WIRE -352 480 -432 480
WIRE -240 480 -240 64
WIRE -240 480 -352 480
WIRE -688 512 -688 480
FLAG -1536 -96 0
FLAG -1536 -240 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -1536 64 Vgate_B_C
FLAG -688 512 0
FLAG -1536 208 0
FLAG -1536 -416 0
FLAG -1536 -560 Vin
FLAG -688 -384 Vin
FLAG -512 -192 0
FLAG -1056 -192 0
FLAG -1056 -272 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -512 16 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -512 -272 Vgate_B_C
FLAG -1056 0 Vgate_B_C
FLAG 224 464 0
FLAG 272 -96 0
FLAG 720 -176 0
FLAG 464 464 0
FLAG 464 304 primary_voltage_drop_due_to_secondary_load
SYMBOL ind2 1472 -352 R270
WINDOW 3 126 -288 VRight 2
WINDOW 39 86 -1 VRight 2
SYMATTR Value Hc = {Hc} Bs = {Bs} Br = {Br} A = {A} Lm = {Lm} Lg = {Lg} N = {N}
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser = 0
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL voltage -1536 -224 R0
WINDOW 3 -876 49 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vgate} 0 {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL sw -976 -192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -432 -192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -976 80 M180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -432 96 M180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL voltage -1536 80 R0
WINDOW 3 -1027 55 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vgate} {1/(2*Fsw)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL voltage -1536 -544 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value {Vin}
SYMBOL voltage 160 -288 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vin*Ns/N} 0 {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMBOL voltage 160 48 R180
WINDOW 0 24 96 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -1020 23 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vin*Ns/N} {0.5/Fsw} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMBOL diode 320 128 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode 320 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 528 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 50µ
SYMBOL res 704 -320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 4
SYMBOL voltage 160 112 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL voltage 160 -368 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL f 224 432 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
WINDOW 123 24 -28 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName F2
SYMATTR Value V8
SYMATTR Value2 {Ns/N}
SYMBOL diode -224 -208 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -224 64 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -1232 64 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -1232 -208 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL res 448 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value {R_disparity}
SYMBOL res -448 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value {R_disparity}
SYMBOL e -432 352 M0
SYMATTR InstName E1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL ind -720 -112 R90
WINDOW 0 5 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 2m
TEXT -1848 -664 Left 2 !.param Hc = 10 Bs = 0.3 Br = 0.2 A = 10u Lm = 1m Lg = 0.725m N = 17
TEXT -1848 -720 Left 2 !.param Fsw = 16k D = 0.45 Vgate = 3.3 Vin = 400
TEXT -1000 -520 Left 2 !.tran 200m
TEXT -592 -752 Left 2 !.model MySwitch SW(Ron=.1 Roff=10Meg Vt=1.65 Vh=-0.5)
TEXT -592 -696 Left 2 !.model MyIdealDiode D(Ron=.1 Roff=10Meg Vfwd=1)
TEXT -1848 -768 Left 2 !.param Ns = 3 R_disparity = 0.01
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you trying to simulate how a transformer saturates? By "staircase transformer" do you mean a square hysteresis, or the square waveform across the transformer (as it appears due to the driving pulses)? I see a floating Chan inductor, so I presume it's the first, but I'm a bit confused by `V5, V6`; are they meant to represent the output of the transformer as it would have been in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wanted to simulate a saturating transformer -- judging by the floating inductor from your schematic (not shown in picture but included in the code) -- all you had to do was to include the Chan core in a coupled inductor's circuit. You could have gone the [ltwiki way](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Transformers) and that would have been a very nice setup, but you can get away a bit cheaper:

[image: Chan core]

Since the Chan core does not allow coupling, `L2` here represents it and `L1` (the primary), together with `L4, L5` (the secondaries), form an ideal transformer with quite large values (1 H for the primary). The Chan core is in parallel with the large value of `L1`, which means the majority of the current will go through `L2`, while the coupling ensures that the voltage ends up in the secondary (I've ogled your values to ~4.3 ratio).

Now, the parameters for `L2`, as set by you, seemd a bit strange: `A=10u` means A = 1e-5 m<sup>2</sup> = 0.1 cm<sup>2</sup> which, for the ~70 V output and 4 Ω load is nowhere near enough. Then `Lm=1m` means the magnetic path length is 1e-3 m = 1 mm which, again, is much too short. So I've changed them to what you see in the picture: 5 cm<sup>2</sup> and 10 cm (some guesses), but I also reduced the gap length by a factor of 1000, since as it was it would have helped the core in case of imbalance (even if not enough). Then, the number of turns for this core was simply too small, fully saturating the core and giving kA worth of current through it; so I increased the value, even if it seems a bit unrealistic. Finally, the imbalance resistor was increased to 1 Ω, and the `.MODEL`s for the switch and the diode were slightly touched.

At any rate, the new core has an inductance of ~67 mH, which is more likely for the chosen switching frequency, but still seems large for the given power, so it's now only about 15x smaller than `L1`. The values could be increased, but be careful that you don't upset the solver.

The plot shows high initial saturation, then some borderline saturated current (the peaks are wavy), then the saturation increases on one side, only (the upper plot, zoomed in at the end), due to the extra resistor. If you add the "ltwiki way", you'll get something very similar:

[image: ltwiki way]

Note that, as you see it above, the coupling is implied to be 1 due to the lack of leaking inductances. In case you want to play with it, below is the code for this last one:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2016 1476
WIRE -1536 -528 -1536 -560
WIRE -1536 -416 -1536 -448
WIRE -976 -384 -1248 -384
WIRE -688 -384 -976 -384
WIRE -432 -384 -688 -384
WIRE -240 -384 -432 -384
WIRE 176 -368 160 -368
WIRE 320 -368 256 -368
WIRE 448 -368 384 -368
WIRE 544 -368 448 -368
WIRE 720 -368 624 -368
WIRE 160 -320 160 -368
WIRE 720 -304 720 -368
WIRE -976 -288 -976 -384
WIRE -432 -288 -432 -384
WIRE -1248 -272 -1248 -384
WIRE -1024 -272 -1056 -272
WIRE -480 -272 -512 -272
WIRE -240 -272 -240 -384
WIRE 160 -272 160 -320
WIRE -1024 -224 -1056 -224
WIRE -480 -224 -512 -224
WIRE -1536 -208 -1536 -240
WIRE -1056 -192 -1056 -224
WIRE -512 -192 -512 -224
WIRE 720 -176 720 -224
WIRE 160 -128 160 -192
WIRE 272 -128 160 -128
WIRE -1536 -96 -1536 -128
WIRE -1248 -96 -1248 -208
WIRE -976 -96 -976 -208
WIRE -976 -96 -1248 -96
WIRE -912 -96 -976 -96
WIRE -832 -96 -912 -96
WIRE -480 -96 -608 -96
WIRE -432 -96 -432 -208
WIRE -432 -96 -480 -96
WIRE -240 -96 -240 -208
WIRE -240 -96 -432 -96
WIRE 272 -96 272 -128
WIRE 160 -48 160 -128
WIRE -976 -16 -976 -96
WIRE -1248 0 -1248 -96
WIRE -1024 0 -1056 0
WIRE -432 0 -432 -96
WIRE -240 0 -240 -96
WIRE -480 16 -512 16
WIRE -1024 48 -1056 48
WIRE -480 64 -512 64
WIRE 160 80 160 32
WIRE -1536 96 -1536 64
WIRE 160 112 160 80
WIRE 176 112 160 112
WIRE 320 112 256 112
WIRE 448 112 448 -368
WIRE 448 112 384 112
WIRE -1536 208 -1536 176
WIRE -432 208 -432 80
WIRE -1248 480 -1248 64
WIRE -1056 480 -1056 48
WIRE -1056 480 -1248 480
WIRE -976 480 -976 64
WIRE -976 480 -1056 480
WIRE -688 480 -976 480
WIRE -512 480 -512 64
WIRE -512 480 -688 480
WIRE -432 480 -432 288
WIRE -432 480 -512 480
WIRE -240 480 -240 64
WIRE -240 480 -432 480
WIRE -688 512 -688 480
WIRE -272 640 -336 640
WIRE -208 640 -272 640
WIRE -64 640 -128 640
WIRE -384 656 -448 656
WIRE -1168 720 -1200 720
WIRE -1024 720 -1088 720
WIRE -960 720 -1024 720
WIRE -848 720 -912 720
WIRE -752 720 -848 720
WIRE -656 720 -752 720
WIRE -544 720 -656 720
WIRE -448 720 -448 656
WIRE -448 720 -544 720
WIRE -272 720 -336 720
WIRE -96 720 -272 720
WIRE -912 736 -912 720
WIRE -272 784 -336 784
WIRE -208 784 -272 784
WIRE -96 784 -96 720
WIRE -96 784 -128 784
WIRE -1024 800 -1200 800
WIRE -960 800 -1024 800
WIRE -448 800 -448 720
WIRE -384 800 -448 800
WIRE -96 800 -96 784
WIRE -272 864 -336 864
WIRE -64 864 -272 864
FLAG -1536 -96 0
FLAG -1536 -240 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -1536 64 Vgate_B_C
FLAG -688 512 0
FLAG -1536 208 0
FLAG -1536 -416 0
FLAG -1536 -560 Vin
FLAG -688 -384 Vin
FLAG -512 -192 0
FLAG -1056 -192 0
FLAG -1056 -272 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -512 16 Vgate_A_D
FLAG -512 -272 Vgate_B_C
FLAG -1056 0 Vgate_B_C
FLAG 272 -96 0
FLAG 720 -176 0
FLAG -912 -96 A
FLAG -480 -96 B
FLAG -1200 800 B
FLAG -1200 720 A
FLAG -64 640 x
FLAG 160 -320 X
FLAG 160 80 y
FLAG -912 784 0
FLAG -848 800 0
FLAG -752 800 0
FLAG -656 800 0
FLAG -544 800 0
FLAG -384 704 0
FLAG -384 848 0
FLAG -64 864 y
FLAG -96 800 0
SYMBOL voltage -1536 -224 R0
WINDOW 3 -876 49 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vgate} 0 {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL sw -976 -192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -432 -192 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -976 80 M180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL sw -432 96 M180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMATTR Value MySwitch
SYMBOL voltage -1536 80 R0
WINDOW 3 -1027 55 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 {Vgate} {1/(2*Fsw)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {1/(Fsw*1000)} {D/Fsw} {1/Fsw})
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL voltage -1536 -544 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value {Vin}
SYMBOL diode 320 128 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode 320 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL ind 528 -352 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 50u
SYMBOL res 704 -320 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 4
SYMBOL voltage 160 112 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL voltage 160 -368 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL diode -224 -208 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -224 64 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -1232 64 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D5
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL diode -1232 -208 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -179 35 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D6
SYMATTR Value MyIdealDiode
SYMBOL res -448 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value {R_disparity}
SYMBOL ind2 -768 704 R0
WINDOW 3 369 152 Right 2
WINDOW 39 64 184 Right 2
SYMATTR Value Hc = {Hc} Bs = {Bs} Br = {Br} A = {A} Lm = {Lm} Lg = {Lg} N = 1
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser = 0
SYMATTR InstName L7
SYMATTR Type ind
SYMBOL f -848 800 M180
WINDOW 0 24 -3 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -10 -26 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName F1
SYMATTR Value Vp1 {N1}
SYMBOL f -656 800 M180
WINDOW 0 27 -4 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -11 -29 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName F2
SYMATTR Value Vs1 {N2}
SYMBOL f -544 800 M180
WINDOW 0 29 0 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -8 -27 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName F3
SYMATTR Value Vs2 {N2}
SYMBOL g -960 704 M0
WINDOW 0 16 4 Left 2
WINDOW 3 5 118 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName G1
SYMATTR Value {N1/Rp}
SYMBOL res -1008 704 M0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value {Rp}
SYMBOL voltage -1184 720 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vp1
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMBOL g -336 624 R0
WINDOW 0 6 5 Left 2
WINDOW 3 2 117 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName G2
SYMATTR Value {N2/Rs}
SYMBOL res -288 624 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value {Rs}
SYMBOL voltage -112 640 M270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vs1
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMBOL g -336 768 R0
WINDOW 0 0 2 Left 2
WINDOW 3 2 119 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName G3
SYMATTR Value {N2/Rs}
SYMBOL res -288 768 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value {Rs}
SYMBOL voltage -112 784 M270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 -32 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vs2
SYMATTR Value ""
TEXT -1000 -464 Left 2 !.param Hc = 10 Bs = 0.3 Br = 0.2 A = 500u Lm = 100m Lg = 0.725u N = 45
TEXT -1848 -720 Left 2 !.param Fsw = 16k D = 0.45 Vgate = 3.3 Vin = 400
TEXT -1000 -520 Left 2 !.tran 2m
TEXT -592 -752 Left 2 !.model MySwitch SW(Ron=.1 Roff=10Meg Vt=1.65 Vh=-1.65)
TEXT -592 -696 Left 2 !.model MyIdealDiode D(Ron=.1 Roff=10Meg Vfwd=0.7 vrev=1k epsilon=0.1 revepsilon=1)
TEXT -1848 -768 Left 2 !.param Ns = 3 R_disparity = 1
TEXT -944 656 Left 2 !.parma N1=N N2=ceil(N/4.3) Rp=0.1 Rs=10m
```

---

[edit]

Given the line of comments, the infinite current that you're expecting will only be valid if there was no resistance, or if the voltage would be applied indefinitely.

So, as a reduction to your case above, think of the whole setup as an RL circuit driven by an imbalanced source. If you look at your circuit, the bridge applies positive, then negative voltage on a source, so it can be reduced, for the sake of analysis. To make things a little bit easier for the explanation below, don't think of the source as a pulse, but as a sine of the same frequency. Therefore, the setup is: a biased sine source driving a series RL load. The values are 1 Ω and 1 H, and the source is of the form \$1+2\sin(\omega t+\phi)\$. This is how the math goes:

$$\begin{align}
H(s)&=\dfrac{sL}{R+sL}=\dfrac{\dfrac{R}{L}s}{s+\dfrac{R}{L}} \tag{1}\\
h(t)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\big(H(s)\big)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{R}{L}t\right) \tag{2} \\
s(t)&=1+2\sin(\omega t+\varphi) \tag{3} \\
y(t)&=\int_0^t{s(\tau)h(t-\tau)\text{d}t} \\
{}&=\int_0^t{(1+2\sin(\omega\tau+\varphi)\exp(-\dfrac{R}{L}(t-\tau))\text{d}t} \\
{}&=\dfrac{2 L {{R}^{2}} \sin{\left( \omega t+\varphi\right) }-2 {{L}^{2}} R \omega \cos{\left( \omega t+\varphi\right) }+{{L}^{3}} {{\omega}^{2}}+L {{R}^{2}}}{{{L}^{2}} R {{\omega}^{2}}+{{R}^{3}}}-\dfrac{\left( 2 L {{R}^{2}} \sin{(\varphi)}-2 {{L}^{2}} R \omega \cos{(\varphi)}+{{L}^{3}} {{\omega}^{2}}+L {{R}^{2}}\right)  }{{{L}^{2}} R {{\omega}^{2}}+{{R}^{3}}}{\exp\left(-\dfrac{R}{L}t\right)} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

It's a beauty, but if you'll replace \$\omega=2\pi 5,\;R=1,\;L=1,\;\phi=-\pi/6\$ and plot this, you get:

[image: RL math]

LTspice very much agrees with the mathematical answer, composed of a pulssating part and a transient part:

[image: LTspice confirms it]

Comment: Your answer was exacty my final objective. Nice job as usual !  Thank you very much. But I still have a question. In the case where I use a linear inductor as in my first simulation, (do not take into account the secondary side), why the current of the magnetizing inductor is not diverging, as I apply due to the extra resistor a voltage across the inductance not equal in value according to what of the 2 switchs are closed ?

Comment: @Jess It's just a linear inductor, and ideal, too, so you can run 1 GA through it and it will never saturate. The same with voltage, only this time it will take a while for the current to settle due to the RL time constant. You can try this in a much simpler way: a voltage source, a limiting series resistor, and an inductor. Make the voltage a pulse from 0 to 1 (k, M, G, etc). The current will always settle to some average value. That "diverging" you mention is due to the saturation, which lowers the value of the overall inductance, hence the current is rising.

Comment: Thank you :) I may be wrong.  According to the formula of an inductance, U = Ldi/dt, ie dt = U/L*dt. For a linear inductor L is constant and I set into the simulation "dt" constant. When "U" is postive and equal to 400V, the current increases and the variation of the current is equal to di_400V, and when "U" is negative and equal to minus 400V plus the voltage drop across the resistor so the current decreases  by a variation not equal to di_400V but legerely lower than it. So It will diverge as the two variations are not equal. There is something that I do not understand...

Comment: @Jess But you're right! On one side there's U, on the other it's U-Rx*I (Rx being the extra R). And that is the steady state, that's where it will converge. Think of it in terms of an averaged circuit: that di/dt becomes an I_avg, and its value is given by the difference between the two applied voltages. Simplify even more: a simple DC voltage source of 1 V with a series RL (say 1 Ohm and 1 H). If the inductor is ideal, will the current rise, or will the inductor become a short (due to DC) and the current stabilize to U/R? Make the source a step and you'll get the transient, too.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean ! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Actually, i still do not get it x) I agree with you on a the RL circuit. On one hand, we always apply a voltage equal to U and other side we apply a voltage U-R*I. And more the current increase, the more the voltage will decrease and so the slope of current will be reduced, whereas on the other side there is nothing for limiting the slope. The slope is always constant, so the current should go to the infini. From my point of view, there is no steady state. If you can do a simulation for showing me that I am wrong ... or some maths I do not know :/

Comment: @Jess The infinite current is only valid if you have a voltage source and an inductor, no resistance. Otherwise, a simple buck regulator would explode in normal conditions. ;-) Still, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRcZS.png) is what I meant with my previous examples. `L1` has straight DC, the current is 1 V / 1 Ohm = 1 A. `L2` has a step of 1 V, it goes through a transient and converges to 1 A. `L3` has a pulse from -1 to 3, thus an average of 1, so it mimics an imbalance. The result is the same average transient, and the same average DC value. The slope continues only until U switches...

Comment: ...to -U, which makes the current turn backwards (again, think of the buck example). And because there is an R, there will never be an infinite value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133255/discussion-between-jess-and-a-concerned-citizen).